# Is there a Web Widget to display Questions with specific Tag?

Tags: discussion, widgets

I'm looking for a widget that I can embed on my own web site. The widget needs to display the latest questions with a specific tag.

Is there such a widget?

I've found StackTack on http://stackapps.com but it only seems to display a specific question rather than a list of questions.

Comment: +1: I'm looking for this too.